# Which is the request limit in Postman and is it a way to change it

Tags: json, rest, request, postman, http-get

I know this is not a very programming question but I searched and didn't find an answer anywhere.

So, after few requests on postman (some simple GET requests that are not so resource consuming) it returns this message:

```
{
    "code": 43,
    "message": "For security reasons you have been blocked for some time as you have exceeded the maximum number of requests per minute."
}
```

Does anybody know which is that limit and what exactly means "some time"?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to be a Postman issue.

It seems to be a response from the API you are consuming using Postman. The API may be a rate limiting. I advise you to check the API documentation for details.

Comment: Could it be this? https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#api-call-limit

Comment: @LeoMessi If you are consuming the Zoho API, then those are the API rate limits being applied. As I mentioned in my answer, it's not something related to Postman.